# Nodes are deactivated/inactive/greyed-out and cannot alter value

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, node-editor

I have nodes but somehow they are greyed out and I am unable to change values. Did I press a hotkey accidentally? If so what was it?

An example is attached below;

[image]

Comment: Can you attach .Blend file?

Comment: @Georges, I'm sorry, I won't be able to. This is a commercial project and I would need to get a special permission from my client.

Comment: A workaround is to delete the lot and create a new material from scratch.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This issue could have been caused by [linking in an object from another scene](https://www.blender.org/manual/data_system/linked_libraries.html). When you link in an object, "ghost" materials are created - completely identical to the materials from the original file, but uneditable.
If this is the case, then simply append objects or materials themselves and you should be able to edit the nodes again.

Comment: Ah, my mistake indeed. I was LINKING, instead of APPENDING.

Comment: This is not the case for me. I am 100% sure I click Append, but the materials are still greyed out.