# Material node tree is locked

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, node-editor, linked-data

I have downloaded a material off the internet and appended the material into my scene, but when I went to the node editor and tried to change the nodes, I can't.
They are simply locked:

[image: cycles nodes]

Notice how the nodes are slightly transparent. How can I unlock the material?

Comment: See http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/51633/nodes-are-deactivated-inactive-greyed-out-and-cannot-alter-value

Answer (score 8):

### Link & Append

There are two different ways of importing a  data-block from another blendfile as said by the [blender references manual's page](https://www.blender.org/manual/data_system/linked_libraries.html):

> **Link** creates a reference to the data in the source file such that
>   changes made there will be reflected in the referencing file the next
>   time it is reloaded.
>
> Whereas **Append** makes a full copy of the data into your blend. You can
>   make further edits to your local copy of the data, but changes in the
>   external source file will not be reflected in the referencing file.

When you **link** a material, you'll not be able to edit that resource.

You can unlink & make the resource local (so you'll be able to edit the data-block) by clicking the little icon next to the material's name in the material tab:

[image]